# return dinamic data string in golang

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func FindSimilarData(input string, data ...string) string {
same := ""
    for _, d := range data {
        fmt.Println(d)

        if (d) == input {
            same += d
            fmt.Println(d)
            fmt.Println(same)
        }
    }
    return "" 
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(FindSimilarData("iphone", "laptop", "iphone 13", "iphone 12", "iphone 12 pro"))
}
```

i want to return the data type string which has similar data, i was trying to use strings. Contains but it only returns the boolean type. can anyone give an example for this one, thanks before

Comment: expect output is : iphone 13,iphone 12, iphone 12 pro

Comment: When you say "similar", do you mean that the input is substring of a data string?

Comment: yeah the full of substring i think

Comment: maybe similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562873/most-idiomatic-way-to-select-elements-from-an-array-in-golang?

Answer (score 0):

If strings.Contains returns true you can append it on a output string and return the string.

```
func FindSimilarData(input string, data ...string) string {
    same := ""
    for _, d := range data {
        fmt.Println(d)

        if strings.Contains(d, input) {
            if len(same) != 0 {
                same += ","
            }
            same += d
        }
    }
    return same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func FindSimilarData(input string, data ...string) string {
    same := ""
    for _, d := range data {
        fmt.Println(d)

        if strings.Contains(d, input) {
            same += d
            same += ","
            fmt.Println(d)
            fmt.Println(same)
        }
    }
    return ""
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(FindSimilarData("iphone", "laptop", "iphone 13", "iphone 12", "iphone 12 pro"))
}
```